# Count the occurrences of just one value in R

Tags: r, vector, count, r-factor

I have 34 subsets with a bunch of variables and I am making a new dataframe with summarizing information about each variable for the subsets. 
 - Example: A10, T2 and V2 are all subsets with ~10 variables and 14 observations where one variable is population.

I want my new dataframe to have a column which says how many times per subset variable 2 hit zero.

I've looked at a bunch of different count functions but they all seem to make separate tables and count the occurrences of all variables. I'm not interested in how many times each unique value shows up because most of the values are unique, I just want to know how many times population hit zero for each subset of 14 observations.

I realize this is probably a simple thing to do but I'm not very good at creating my own solutions from other R code yet. Thanks for the help.

I've done something similar with a different dataset where I counted how many times 'NA' occurred in a vector where all the other values were numerical. For that I used:

```
    na.tmin<- c(sum(is.na(s1997$TMIN)), sum(is.na(s1998$TMIN)), sum(is.na(s1999$TMIN))...
```

Which created a column (na.tmin) that had the number of times each subset recorded NA instead of a number. I'd like to just count the number of times the value 0 occurred but is.0 is of course not a function because 0 is numerical. Is there a function that will just count the number of times a specific value shows up? If there's not should I use the count occurrences for unique values function?

Comment: The notion of "how many times population hit zero for each subset" needs a bit of explanation. You may have difficulty with creating solutions, but you really do need to use some R code to create the problem so we can attempt a solution.

Comment: Take a look at the `sapply` function. Across all subsets you can apply a function, which counts the unique values of the population, then subset this to get just the number of times 0 appears.

Comment: You can still use `sum` like so: `sum(A10$population==0)` to count the number of `0`'s in a particular subset. If you have multiple datasets, you might be best off collecting them all in a `list` like `allsubs <- list(A10, T2)` and then you can `lapply` your `sum` function across each of the datasets - `lapply(allsubs, function(x) sum(x$population==0) )`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
sum( abs( s1997$TMIN ) < 0.00000001 )
```

It's safer to use a tolerance value unless you are sure that you value is an integer. See FAQ 7.31.

```
sum( abs( pi - (355/113+seq(-0.001, 0.001, length=1000 ) ) )< 0.00001 )
[1] 10
```